# If we can exchange one feat per level up, then can those feats be racial or class feats?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, feats

Can you replace feats that you get as class features, but that you'll never use for reasons unique to your character?  Can we, for example, take those useless feats at a rate of one per level and re-purpose them for feats that we'll actually use?

In may case, I have a fighter that doesn't believe in wearing armor, and so doesn't need heavy, medium, or light armor proficiency.  I did a search on Google and can't seem to find anywhere what this has been addressed yet - I only see that we can exchange 1 feat or power per level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In short, no.**

The rules that you're asking about are on Page 28 of the PHB, under 'Retraining'.  The relevant line is:

> You can’t replace a feat if it’s a prerequisite for any other
>   attribute you have (another feat or a paragon path, for
>   example), or if the feat is a feature of your class, path,
>   or destiny (as the Ritual Caster feat is a class feature
>   for wizards).

Since armour proficiency is a class feature of Fighters and not a feat selection, you can't replace it.